# $\prod_{k=2}^n (k^2 - k)$: is WolframAlpha wrong?

Tags: products, wolfram-alpha

I tried to find the product of $k(k-1)$ from $k=2$ to $n$.

The partial product values should be 12 at 3 and 144 at 4. But it's showing the wrong partial product. What went wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqDgU.jpg)

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5Bk(k-1),%7Bk,2,n%7D%5D) looks ok to me.

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: I don't know why WolframAlpha is showing different result for the same query!

Comment: "Works for me too"  If you look down at the table of values, it shows what we expect.  If you expand the "partial products" tab with the button "show points" it gives what the OP points out as seemingly incorrect information.  So, that begs the question, what information does the "show points" button convey and how does that differ from the table of values below?

Comment: To reiterate the point:  If you click "show points" it gives the "Partial product values: $(2,1),(3,2),(4,12),(5,144),\dots$"  while if you instead scroll down the page to the section labeled Values you instead see "Values $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}\hline 1&2&3&4\\\hline 1&2&12&144\\\hline\end{array}$"

Comment: My *assumption* is that it treats the "first partial product" as the partial product with one term, i.e. the partial product that occurs when $n=2$.  It treats the "second partial product" as the partial product with two terms, i.e. the partial product that occurs when $n=3$, etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz: I'm pretty sure that this is the answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz But when $n=2$, the partial product should be $2$, as in the table. I don't see how to interpret the point at abscissa $2$ to find $1$ as ordinate. I *could* understand the other way around ($2$ at abscissa $1$) to be what you describe.

Comment: It seems like products have an oopsie in their code.. Add it to the pile of bugs in Wolfram products.